# Tesla coil secondary wire problem

Tags: tesla-coil

I'm making a small Tesla coil and I need to add some wire on the secondary coil because the one I used is too short. 
I have 2 wires with the same length. Can i add them to the first?
If i do this the tesla coil, will it work using a slayer exciter circuit?

Comment: It's pretty unclear to me what you're asking, perhaps you could add a photo and schematic to explain it further?

Answer (score 1):

A join in the secondary is bad electrically as well as aesthetically.

Any non-uniformity in the electric field along the secondary will be a weak point for premature electrical breakdown.

Any lump in the secondary will look like you didn't care about the beauty of the finished object.